# condition in sql database

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I create a condition in sql? To be more specific I need to execute the command to return true / false.

For example: There will be 1000 records in the user database, and if I want to make a query that will return true / false if there is, for example, Steve in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
select max(user = 'Steve')
from t;
```

This returns `0` for false and `1` for true.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something trivial :D

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all true records if you want just to see if its true delete the star in the select statement.

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN [user] = 'Steve' then 'true' else 'false' END AS [TRUE/FALSE]
 , *
 FROM tbl
--- if you want just true records uncomment the below lines
--- WHERE CASE WHEN [user] = 'Steve' then 'true' else 'false' END = 'true'
order by 1 desc
```